# Running elastic search in development mode on different hosts

Tags: elasticsearch

we used elastic for quite some time and are quite happy with it but now it's beginning to perform excessive GC.

I wanted to add another node (on an other host (the current host doesn't have much memory left)) but if you configure networking, warnings (vm.max_map_count not being big enough is one of them) become errors and cease the node to start.

We don't have root on the machines and also can't request root required operations.

I also asked the question [on discuss elastic](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/running-multiple-nodes-in-development-mode/103396) and betting on multiple horses here (I also don't know whether this belongs on Super User, if so, pardon my mistake)

Can you run Elastic in development mode on different hosts, if so, how, if not, are there other solutions?

Thanks,

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case we didn't need all of the data all of the time,

We now use [snapshots](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) to 'swap out' old unneeded data to the file system (out of memory) from within the kibana interface so when we do need old data we can easily 'swap' it back 'in' with that same interface.

-> No excessive GC anymore

-> *long term solution* -> you can just keep swapping out the old data until you don't have any diskspace left (which will be probably never) and we can always swap, on the index level, data back in... (our indexes are daily and even broken down further so the granularity is more than sufficient)

For more info there was also an answer in the link in the original question...